# When i try to start the rails server i get an error of bug segmantation fault in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.5

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0103 p:---- s:0557 e:000556 CFUNC  :connect
c:0102 p:0612 s:0545 e:000544 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90 [FINISH]
c:0101 p:---- s:0531 e:000530 CFUNC  :new
c:0100 p:0142 s:0526 e:000525 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25
c:0099 p:0024 s:0519 e:000518 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729
c:0098 p:0021 s:0515 e:000514 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773
c:0097 p:0015 s:0511 e:000510 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752
c:0096 p:0014 s:0505 e:000504 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:713
c:0095 p:0012 s:0499 e:000497 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490
c:0094 p:0031 s:0493 e:000489 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364
c:0093 p:0046 s:0486 e:000485 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883
c:0092 p:0011 s:0479 e:000478 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128
c:0091 p:0004 s:0475 e:000474 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91
c:0090 p:0018 s:0471 e:000470 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:43
c:0089 p:0099 s:0463 e:000462 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:116
c:0088 p:0026 s:0457 e:000454 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:706
c:0087 p:0013 s:0448 e:000447 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:583
c:0086 p:0004 s:0443 e:000442 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260
c:0085 p:0004 s:0439 e:000438 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38
c:0084 p:0239 s:0431 E:000550 BLOCK  /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/app/admin/admin_users.rb:63 [FINISH]
c:0083 p:---- s:0425 e:000424 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0082 p:0013 s:0421 e:000420 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15
c:0081 p:0029 s:0416 e:000415 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:242
c:0080 p:0036 s:0410 E:000030 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:70
c:0079 p:0030 s:0402 E:000710 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:65
c:0078 p:0018 s:0394 E:0020c0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin.rb:73
c:0077 p:0018 s:0386 E:001b80 TOP    /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/app/admin/admin_users.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0076 p:---- s:0383 e:000382 CFUNC  :load
c:0075 p:0011 s:0377 E:001d80 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0074 p:0049 s:0374 E:001e30 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259
c:0073 p:0015 s:0368 E:001d58 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0072 p:0009 s:0361 E:001f10 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:123
c:0071 p:0002 s:0358 E:001fb8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/error.rb:43
c:0070 p:0011 s:0353 E:001ee8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:123
c:0069 p:0007 s:0348 E:002078 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:115 [FINISH]
c:0068 p:---- s:0344 e:000343 CFUNC  :each
c:0067 p:0037 s:0340 E:0019b0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:115
c:0066 p:0004 s:0336 E:000c88 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:141
c:0065 p:0018 s:0331 E:000cb0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/lib/active_admin.rb:77
c:0064 p:0031 s:0323 E:000b40 BLOCK  /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/config/routes.rb:4 [FINISH]
c:0063 p:---- s:0320 e:000319 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0062 p:0040 s:0316 E:001690 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391
c:0061 p:0017 s:0310 E:001ad8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:373
c:0060 p:0017 s:0305 E:002160 TOP    /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/config/routes.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0059 p:---- s:0302 e:000301 CFUNC  :load
c:0058 p:0011 s:0296 E:0014f0 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0057 p:0049 s:0293 E:0021e0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259
c:0056 p:0015 s:0287 E:0015d8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287
c:0055 p:0007 s:0280 E:001458 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40 [FINISH]
c:0054 p:---- s:0276 e:000275 CFUNC  :each
c:0053 p:0008 s:0272 E:0006e0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40
c:0052 p:0009 s:0268 E:000390 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16
c:0051 p:0005 s:0264 E:001070 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26 [FINISH]
c:0050 p:0023 s:0261 E:0006e0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77
c:0049 p:0038 s:0257 E:0010d8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27
c:0048 p:0004 s:0252 E:0000b0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7
c:0047 p:0012 s:0244 E:0025f0 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119 [FINISH]
c:0046 p:---- s:0239 e:000238 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0045 p:0015 s:0234 E:002558 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30
c:0044 p:0019 s:0229 E:000fe8 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55
c:0043 p:0019 s:0225 E:000718 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228
c:0042 p:0005 s:0221 E:002558 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350
c:0041 p:0109 s:0217 E:002380 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431
c:0040 p:0031 s:0205 E:0011f8 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349 [FINISH]
c:0039 p:---- s:0201 e:000200 CFUNC  :each
c:0038 p:---- s:0198 e:000197 CFUNC  :call
c:0037 p:0033 s:0194 E:000910 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347
c:0036 p:0034 s:0186 E:000420 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226
c:0035 p:0033 s:0180 E:000348 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205
c:0034 p:0022 s:0173 E:001ef0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54
c:0033 p:0023 s:0167 E:001b88 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352
c:0032 p:0020 s:0162 E:000280 TOP    /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/config/environment.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0159 e:000158 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0030 p:0006 s:0154 E:0018d0 EVAL   /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/config.ru:3 [FINISH]
c:0029 p:---- s:0151 e:000150 CFUNC  :eval
c:0028 p:0033 s:0144 E:001750 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116
c:0027 p:0134 s:0136 E:001a08 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105
c:0026 p:0031 s:0127 E:0023b8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66
c:0025 p:0083 s:0120 E:001d40 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349
c:0024 p:0035 s:0114 E:001270 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249
c:0023 p:0020 s:0110 E:000fc8 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84
c:0022 p:0019 s:0105 E:000e20 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422
c:0021 p:0004 s:0100 E:001a98 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:148
c:0020 p:0038 s:0095 E:001f50 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:102
c:0019 p:0042 s:0091 E:0009b8 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0087 e:000086 CFUNC  :tap
c:0017 p:0028 s:0083 E:001450 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85
c:0016 p:0028 s:0079 E:000c38 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49
c:0015 p:0115 s:0074 E:0022c0 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0069 e:000068 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0053 s:0064 E:000028 TOP    /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/bin/rails:9 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0134 s:0055 E:001268 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28
c:0010 p:0009 s:0050 E:002438 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
c:0009 p:0014 s:0045 E:0020e0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30
c:0008 p:0293 s:0039 E:001208 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0033 e:000032 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0115 s:0028 E:001448 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0129 s:0017 E:0019a0 TOP    /home/jenish/intellolabs/praman/exchange_platform_bidding/bin/spring:15 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0012 e:000011 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0018 s:0007 E:000948 EVAL   bin/rail
```

I have tried reinstalling mysql in my server again and even reinstalled ruby as well

my ruby is version 2.5.1 rails version is 5.0.7.2 and mysql version is 0.5.3

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be indicating an issue with connecting to a MySQL database using the mysql2 adapter. To solve the issue, I would recommend checking the configuration details in your database.yml file, making sure that the database is running, and verifying that the connection details (username, password, host, database name) are correct. You may also want to check the error logs on the database server to see if there are any related error messages. Additionally, it could be a good idea to update the mysql2 gem to the latest version.

Comment: Done everything mentioned here still the same error continues